# Objective C: Names, Bindings, and Scopes

Tags: objective-c, c, variables, binding, scope

I am looking to acquire information about how Objective-C identifies an entity in a program. How many characters are allowed, etc. I have tried to Google it, but I couldn't come up with anything. Since it was party based on C, does the naming/binding/scope follow that of C? Any help would be appreciated. If you have any links that talk about these things it would also be helpful. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Not following the question. Are you talking about the allowed length of symbol names for example?

Comment: Yes. Like Fortran 95+ allows up to 31 characters in its names. C++ has no length limit, but some implementors do. I also need to know other things like all variables in PHP must start with a dollar sign. I also need to know about case sensitivity. It is a pretty easy question haha. I just cannot find the answer anywhere. I think it probably is the same as C, but I am not sure. I also need to know all of the reserved and keywords in Objective-C.

Comment: Im not aware that there is one. At least I never hit it. iOS6 is famous for its VERY long verbose names. I suggest you just have at it until you hit a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C follows the same rules as C, then adds a couple of its own for the OO features not found in C.

As in C, there is no hard limit on the number of characters you can have in a variable name.

Scope and visibility rules are the same as in C, although Objective-C objects are almost always accessed through pointers — and the lifetime of the objects themselves are [managed either through reference counting or garbage collection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i) — so scope is somewhat less important than in C or C++.

The one major difference is that instance variables are scoped to the instance that they belong to, and [you can control whether outside callers can access them](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127) with the `@public`, `@protected` and `@private` keywords.

One other kinda-difference is blocks. They're a nonstandard<sup>†</sup> addition to C that Apple has made. Blocks capture the scope around them, keeping things around as long as the block exists. Blocks also normally retain objects they reference to make sure those objects don't get released. You can read about the specifics in Apple's [block programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

<sup>†</sup><sub>Apple has submitted blocks for standardization, but it hasn't happened yet and may never actually happen, though it would be pretty nice if it did.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Do you have any references for this information? Besides the block programming guide? Thank-You!

Comment: @JLott: I added references to to the docs for the other Objective-C features I mentioned. Hope that helps.